# I want to add through this button if numbers are not same display popup not equal

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add through this button if numbers are not same, then display a popup:

> not equal

please if someone can do this

Here is the code link https://jsfiddle.net/xr2o6jh3/1/

```
$("input.text").on('change paste input', function(){
      if($("#text1").val()!==$("#text2").val()){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xr2o6jh3/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You may wish to review [ask] for some guidelines on posting your questions.  Please include your code as a [mcve] in the body of your question.  As a reminder, SO is not a free coding service-- it is expected that you will show what you have attempted thus far towards resolving the issue yourself.

Comment: Instead of listen to the input events `change paste input`. Listen to the button click - $(`.btn-primary`).on('click' ...`